# Image from access database with Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a picture of an Access database from visual studio
this is my code:

```
   var DBPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Bd.mdb";
Console.Write("Ruta: " + Application.StartupPath);
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;"+"DataSource=" + DBPath);
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT * from Bono", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            sorteo = (string)dt.Rows[0]["Sorteo"];
            fecha = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["Fecha"];
            labelFecha.Text = fecha.Day.ToString() + "/" + fecha.Month.ToString() + "/" + fecha.Year.ToString();
            byte[] data = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Imagen"];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Lista.Image = Image.FromStream(ms,false);
        }
```

but it gives me this exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' System.Drawing.dll 
in the line: Lista.Image = Image.FromStream(ms,false);

Comment: Whenever you are sharing exception info in a question, be sure to click "[Copy exception detail to the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/)" and put the full exception details in your question. There is information inside of the exception that contains useful data to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `FromStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) you will see the only two reasons it will throw a `ArgumentException` is if the stream you passed in is null (which is impossible for your case) or the bytes in the stream does not represent a valid image format.

Check that the data you are reading out is a valid image, save the content to a file using `File.WriteAllBytes("someFileName", data)` and try opening it with a image viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried and not the image is opened. I guess that will not saved the image well in the database. I'll check the Access database.

Answer (score -1):

The `Image.FromStream` method requires a **Stream** argument, but you provided a **MemoryStream** argument. Hence the argument exception error.

Comment: MemoryStream inherits from Stream. Please [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) to see what causes a `ArgumentException` to be thrown.